# Unexpected "Identifier" in class body error when using export in Godot 4.0.2

Tags: game-engine, game-development, godot

I'm currently working on a project in Godot 4.0.2 and I'm having trouble using the export keyword in my scripts. Every time I try to use it, I get an "Unexpected 'Identifier' in class body" error. I'm not sure what's causing this error or how to fix it.

Here's an example of the code I'm trying to use:

extends Node2D

export var growth_time = 10.0
var is_grown = false

I've tried searching for solutions online, but I haven't found anything that has helped. Can anyone explain what's causing this error and how to fix it? Additionally, is there anything I can do to prevent this error from occurring in the future?

[image: click here for image]

Answer (score 6):

This is a variable called `growth_time`, its type is Variant:

```
# Godot 3.x or Godot 4.x
var growth_time
```

Here the variable is still a Variant, but it is initialized with a `float` value:

```
# Godot 3.x or Godot 4.x
var growth_time = 10.0
```

To export the variable (so it is available in the inspector), in Godot 3.x you did this:

```
# Godot 3.x
export (float) var growth_time
```

Since the variable is of type Variant, it cannot be exported without specifying a type. Here the variable is being exported as `float`.

However, the variable is still a Variant. It could have values that are not `float` if you set them from code. But it will show as an `float` in the inspector.

We need to fix that. Because in Godot 4.x, you don't do that. In fact, we could have fixed that in Godot 3.x, it looked like this:

```
# Godot 3.x
export var growth_time:float = 10.0
```

Or since you are initializing it, we can set the type implicitly:

```
# Godot 3.x
export var growth_time := 10.0
```

Now the variable is a `float` (either defined explicitly or inferred from the value you are using to initialize it), so we don't need to write `float` in `export`, because exporting a ´float´ as a `float` is the default (well, the other options to export a `float` are also `float` but you can specify a range or use an exponential scale).

*Yes, Godot 3.x had typed variables. It is not a type hint.*

And now, this is how that looks like in Godot 4.x:

```
# Godot 4.x
@export var growth_time:float = 10.0
```

Or like this:

```
# Godot 4.x
@export var growth_time := 10.0
```

That is because `export` is no longer a keyword, but an annotation instead. Annotations are a new language feature in GDScript 2.0 (the one that comes with Godot 4.x), and they all start with `@`.

*This answer is adapted from another answer by me, over at gamedev ([link](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/205127/10408)).*